# Checking App Version via text file

Tags: c#

I need help and this is not giving me any errors but it is not working either :/

If someone can help I would appreciate it.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://sitebuilder.yola.com/restricted_view/site_design/8a4986ca3fa8df50013fb4a713810fe3/resources/program_hudtool/version_hudtool.txt");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string newestversion = sr.ReadToEnd();
string currentversion = Application.ProductVersion;

if (newestversion.Contains(currentversion))
{
this.Text = "Test [Version 0.5] | No Update Available";
}
else
{
this.Text = "Test [Version 0.5] | Update Available: " + sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: When debugging this, what are the values of `newestversion` and `currentversion`?

Comment: You can't do `sr.ReadToEnd()` twice like that. You already have it in the `newestversion` variable, use that instead the second time.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Thanks but that still does not fix my problem.

Comment: @David currentversion = 0.5 | newestversion = 0.5

Comment: @JoshOzeri can you be more explicit about what is not working? Is it setting the Text property?

Comment: @Blorgbeard in the designer I have different text from what is being set in the code above and it does not change at all, it is the same text in the designer...

Comment: Did you step through this code in the debugger? What does it do? Maybe an exception is thrown somewhere and caught silently somewhere else.

Comment: I just moved the code to public Form1() instead of Form1_Load and it kinda works, it gives an error saying "The server returned 403: Forbidden"

Comment: Sounds like you have the wrong address or something. You can see the error just by going to http://sitebuilder.yola.com/restricted_view/site_design/8a4986ca3fa8df50013fb4a713810fe3/resources/program_hudtool/version_hudtool.txt in a browser. I guess you need to sort that out with whoever gave you that URL..

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you get correct versions from both ends (web and local).

```
string newestversion = sr.ReadToEnd();
string currentversion = Application.ProductVersion;

//Test if both versions are valid.
//Debug.WriteLine(newestversion );
//Debug.WriteLine(currentversion );

Version vOnline=new Version(newestversion)
Version vLocal=new Version(currentversion )

if(vOnline > vLocal)
{
}
else
{
}
```